# Consider Calling ConfigureAwait on the awaited task

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext, configureawait

I'm developing an web API using CQRS pattern. I have a command to Create Author.

Here is my Command Handler:

```cs
internal sealed class AddCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateAuthorCommand, Author>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public AddCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
    }

    public async Task<Result<Author>> Handle(CreateAuthorCommand command)
    {
        var nameResult = Name.Create(command.FirstName, command.LastName);
        var birthDateResult = BirthDate.Create(command.DateOfBirth);
        var mainCategoryResult = Entities.Authors.MainCategory.Create(command.MainCategory);

        var authorResult = Result.Combine(nameResult, birthDateResult, mainCategoryResult)
                            .Map(() => new Author(nameResult.Value, birthDateResult.Value, null, mainCategoryResult.Value));

        if (authorResult.IsFailure)
            return Result.Failure<Author>(authorResult.Error);

        await _unitOfWork.AuthorRepository.AddAsync(authorResult.Value);

        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Result.Success(authorResult.Value);
    }
}
```

I have `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` and `Roslynator.Analyzers` nuget packages installed in my project. These packages shows the following Warning and Message for `await _unitOfWork.AuthorRepository.AddAsync(authorResult.Value)` and `await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()`.

> [CA2007](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2007?view=vs-2019) Consider Calling ConfigureAwait on the awaited task

> [RCS1090](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/analyzers/RCS1090.md) Call 'ConfigureAwait(false).'

There are lots of questions posted on this `.ConfigureAwait`

But can anyone explain me in layman terms on why I should do this? Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` removed the warning and message. But I need to understand this clearly on when to `.ConfigureAwait(true)` and when to `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Please assist and teach me.

Comment: [This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#why-would-i-want-to-use-configureawaitfalse) explains it quite well

Comment: My question is since this is an API project I don't need to worry on synchronization context and I can always chain `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to my `await` calls?

Comment: If your API does not accept delegates from the caller, then yes, do use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere in your library. If it does accept delegates then invoking them outside of a sync context could be an issue. You can see [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Asynchronous-action-execution#synchronizationcontext) how the Polly library dealt with this dilemma.